# How to configure `git branch -d` to delete branch only if merged in to current branch

Tags: git, git-branch

The behavior of `git branch -d someBranchName` is almost perfect, except that sometimes it deletes branches that aren't actually merged in to the current checked out branch, just because they have a remote branch.  [Ugh, of course they have a remote branch that I pushed, I don't want to delete them just because they happen to have a remote branch on origin.]

How do I change Git's behavior to only `git branch -d` branches that are merged into the current branch, or is there an alternate command that I can alias that does the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there isn't a way to tell Git to do this. From the man page for `git branch`:

> `-d, --delete`
>
> Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in `HEAD` if no upstream was set with `--track` or `--set-upstream`.

A workaround would be to unset the upstream for the branch you're trying to delete, attempt the delete, and restore the upstream if needed. However, that'd be a pain to do by hand, so let's try to automate it.

From [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/16879922/2747593), get the upstream for given branch:

```
upstream=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref <branch>@{u})
```

Unset the upstream:

```
git branch --unset-upstream <branch>
```

After that, you can use the normal safe-delete:

```
git branch -d <branch>
```

If the branch wasn't deleted, restore the upstream:

```
git branch -u $upstream $1
```

To put it all together in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script (adding some logic in case a branch doesn't have an upstream):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

unset=0
upstream=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref $1@{u})
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  unset=1
  git branch --unset-upstream $1
fi

git branch -d $1

if [ $? -ne 0 && unset ]
then
  git branch -u $upstream $1
fi
```

Or, simplifying it down to an alias:

```
[alias]
    delete-maybe = "! unset=0; upstream=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref $1@{u} 2>/dev/null); [ $? -eq 0 ] && unset=1 && git branch --unset-upstream $1; git branch -d $1; [ $? -ne 0 ] && [ $unset -eq 1 ] && git branch -u $upstream $1; true"
```

You can now use this to safe-delete a branch:

```
git delete-maybe mybranch
```

Comment: Damn, loses git branch completion, though, so it becomes mostly unusable with standard long-branch names.  There any way to still autocomplete the branch, as with bash alias git completions: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash ?

Comment: @Kzqai [This answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/11469302/2747593) looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in for this, so you would have to write a script.  (Then you will need to make sure you use your script instead of Git's built-in `git branch -d`.  The straightforward way is to train yourself to run a different command, but this can be tough.  The sneaky way is to insert your own alternative front-end `git` command.  For more on that, search for, e.g., bash alias tricks to run something other than the system `git` when you run `git args`: your something-else can then check to see whether *`args`* will invoke `git branch` and run your other command instead.  Or, just put your own `git` script in your own `bin` or `scripts` directory, and then call out the system `git` from there.)

To do this *in* a script you just need two items:

1. The current branch.  To read the current branch, use `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.  This will either print the full name of the current branch:

   ```
   $ git symbolic-ref HEAD
   refs/heads/master
   ```

   or it will fail entirely, printing a message to stderr, if you're not on a named branch (i.e., are in "detached HEAD" mode):

   ```
   $ git symbolic-ref HEAD
   fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
   ```

   You may also use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to get the short name of the current branch:

   ```
   $ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
   master
   ```

   but this will just print `HEAD` when you're in "detached HEAD" mode.  (It's up to you to decide how you want your script to work for this case.)  Since `HEAD` is by definition the current branch, you can even skip the `rev-parse` step and just use the literal string `HEAD` here.
2. Test whether the proposed-to-delete branch name resolves to a commit that is an ancestor of the current branch.  The command that does this is `git merge-base` with option `--is-ancestor`:

   ```
   if git merge-base --is-ancestor $to_be_deleted HEAD; then
       ... really delete it ...
   else
       ... complain ...
   fi
   ```

Assuming you're OK with the detached HEAD behavior so that we need only item 2, we can wrap this into a one-liner:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor $maybedel HEAD && \
    git branch -d $maybedel || \
    echo "error: $maybedel is not an ancestor of HEAD"
```

(this is slightly flawed since it prints the error if `git branch -d` fails for some unrelated reason, but it's probably good enough).